# Volunteer Report does not report on 'Role'

Tags: reports, civivolunteer

When I assign volunteers to shifts via the 'Assign Volunteers' screen, the roles are missing from the Volunteer Report.
When I assign volunteers to shifts via the api though, the Volunteer Report shows their roles.
But if i remove the same volunteers from a role via the 'Assign Volunteers' screen, to mark them as available, then again the Volunteer Report is not responding and shows the person as still having the initial role that the api was able to assign.
Am i doing something wrong? This happens on the latest Civi 4.7.19 on wordpress , but also on a new clean install of Civi 4.7.14 on wordpress .

Comment: Interestingly the Volunteer Roster displays the roles correctly. It seems to access the role data via an api call instead of via an sql query like i see in the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've found a bug in CiviVolunteer, which I've been able to reproduce, but it's not with the report -- it's with the assignment.

If you assign the volunteer by dragging them from "Available Volunteers" to a volunteer opportunity, the role is erroneously not populated. You can see this by opening up the contact's record and inspecting the activity on the activity tab.

If you assign the volunteer using the magnifying class in the top right corner of the volunteer opportunity, the role is populated as when you use the API. You can validate this by opening up the contact's record and inspecting the activity on the activity tab.

Comment: I created issue VOL-303: "Drag-and-drop volunteer assignment misses fields 'role' and 'scheduled time'"